# How do bits become a byte?

Tags: byte

Possibly the most basic computer question of all time, but I have not been able to find a straightforward answer and it is driving me crazy. When a computer 'reads' a byte, does it read it as a sequential series of ones and zeros one after the other, or does it somehow read all 8 ones and zeros at once?

Comment: Just from the title, I assumed it was because they drink their milk?

Comment: It depends on what read you mean (hard drive? RAM?) among many other things, and is probably very hardware-dependent.

Comment: As it is I'm afraid your question is too broad and unclear.

Comment: Gravity pulls them together

Answer (score 2):

A computer system reads the data in both ways depending upon type of operation and the how the digital system is designed.I'll explain this with very simple example of a Full adder circuit.

A full adder adds binary numbers and accounts for values carried in as well as out (Wikipedia)

[image]

**Example of Parallel operation**

Suppose in some task we need to add two 8 bit(1 byte) numbers such that all bits are available at the time of addition.
Then in that case we can design a digital system with 8 full-adders(1 for each bit).

[image]

**Example of Serial Operation**

In some other task you observe that all 8 bits will not be simultaneously available.
**Or** you think having 8 separate adders is costly as you need to implement other mathematical operations (like subtraction,multiplication and division). So instead of having 8 separate units you have 1 unit which will individually process bits. In this scenario we will need  three storage units ( Shift Registers) such that two storage units will store two 8-bit numbers and one storage units will store the result .At a given clock pulse single bit will be transmitted from each of two registers to the full adder which will perform the addition process and transfer 1 bit result to the result shift register in single clock pulse.

[image]

This figure contains some additional stuff which is not useful for this thread but you can 
study digital logic design and computer architecture if you want to go more deep in this stuff.

[Shift register](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_register)

[Shift register operations demo](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/0f/4-Bit_PISO_Shift_Register_Seq.gif)

Answer (score 0):

the processor works with a defined number of registerlength. 8, 16, 32, 64 ... think about a register as an amount of connection, one for each bit... thats the amount of bits that will be processed at once in one processor core, one register at once ... the processor hat different kinds of register, examples are the private instruction register or the public data or adress register

Answer (score 0):

This is really kind of outside the scope of Stackoverflow, but it brings back such fond memories from college.

It depends.  Some times a computer reads bits one at a time.  For example over older ethernet [manchester code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manchester_code) is used.  However over old parallel printer cables, there were 8 pins each one signaling a bit, and an entireoctet (byte) is sent at once.

In serial (one-bit-at-a-time) encodings, you're typically measuring transitions in the line or transitions against some well-defined clock source.

In parallel encodings, you're typically reading all the bits into a register at a time and latching the register.
Look up flipflops, registers, and logic gates for information on the low-level parts of this.

Answer (score 0):

> Bits are transmitted **one at a time in serial transmission**, and
>   **multiple numbers of bits in parallel transmission**. A bitwise operation
>   optionally process bits one at a time. Data transfer rates are usually
>   measured in decimal SI multiples of the unit bit per second (bit/s),
>   such as kbit/s.

[Wikipedia's article on Bit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit)

Answer (score 0):

Think of it this way, at least at a physical level: In a transmission cable from point A to B (A and B can be anything, hard drive, CPU, RAM, USB, etc.) each wire in that cable can transmit one bit at a time. Both A and B have a clock pulsing at the same rate. On each pulse, the sender changes the amount of power going down each wire to signify the value of the new bit(s). So, the # of wires in the cable = the # of bits that can be transmitted each "pulse". (Note: This is a very simplified and theoretical explanation).

At a software level, in the CPU, you can never address anything smaller than a byte. You can "access" and manipulate specific bytes by using the bitwise operators (& (AND), | (OR), << (Left Shift), >> (Right Shift), ^ (XOR)).

In hardware, the number of bits being sent each pulse is completely dependent of the hardware itself.